# Как получить имя роута в middleware express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {


  console.log(req.?, 'routename');


  next();
});
```

Собственно как можно получить имя роутера ?

Comment: Можешь конкретнее объяснить, что требуется и зачем?

Comment: @elmigranto если использовать обычный роут app.get(...) и в обьекте req есть свойство route, но в app.use(...) в обьекте req нету такого свойства тк это middleware

Comment: А зачем он тебе? Просто `req.route` считается для выбора обработчика пути, знать который на момент выполнения кода внутри `app.use()` не нужно, судя по тому, что его там нет.